# On button first disable the button then perform service call in Angular7

Tags: angular

I have been given a task on disabling a button. Now the onClick of that button [Approve/Reject] does Rest API service call so basically the ask is, the moment button is clicked, disable it and then perform the backend service call. Below is the UI code for button:

I am new to UI so need a better approach to fulfil the above task. Can someone help me out here. And since we are using Angular code in our application, response related to Angular 6/7 would be really helpful.

Code

```
<button class ="btn btn-primary" (click)= "approve(obj)"> Approve </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [disabled]

here is a short stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cm34df?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
export class FooComponent {
  waitingForResponse = false;

  approve(obj: string): void {
    this.waitingForResponse = true;
    //fakeAPICall
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.waitingForResponse = false;
    }, 3000);
  }
}

<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="waitingForResponse" (click)="approve('test')"> Approve </button>
```

Comment: Thank You Emanuel.. Whatever you shared in the code link that is exactly what I want. But there is a slight problem, in my existing code already a disabled attribute is being used ::
<button class ="btn btn-primary" (click)= "approve(obj)" [disabled]="obj.approveDisabled"> Approve </button>. And this obj.approveDisabled is used for other functionality..Could you please some other ways.

Comment: maybe you could make approveDisabled = true whilst waiting for the API response, to combine the two.

Comment: Even I tried the same and yes I knw thats gonna work.. But this approvedDisabled has its own functionality altogether.. So I dont wanna mess with some existing functionality. Thats why was searching for an alternative way to disabled. DO let me know if you know any alternative way for this.